# iptables performance optimization

Tags: linux, performance, iptables, optimization

Iptables can be optimized by putting the mostly used rule on the top such as the known *related* rule that matches after connection establishment. Also, optimization can be done by using jumps to avoid very long chains. [This link](http://www.linif.org/~joeg/iptables/iptc.html#SESSION_4) shows an example.

My question is about optimizing the rule itself. How the performance will be by adding and/or deleting some checks in a specific rule? What about the order of these checks? For example, this rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s source_ip -d dest_ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

can be rewritten as:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s source_ip -d dest_ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Both rules will allow http traffic from specific source to specific destination. Do you think there will be a performance difference between the two? Also, the checks can be re-ordered as:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -s source_ip -d dest_ip -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Will this also make a difference or iptables will automatically take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s source_ip -d dest_ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

and

> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -s source_ip -d dest_ip -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

create system call iptc_append_entry() with the same arguments.

> iptables -A FORWARD -s source_ip -d dest_ip -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

create system call iptc_append_entry() with other ipt_entry struct(without iniface)... I think the performance will not change

Answer (score 1):

no, as you're just reordering strings that are fed to the command options parser.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever in doubt, enter the `iptables` line you're investigating, and do an `iptables-save | less` afterwards.